# Can AudioKit detect Polyphonic Frequencies?

Tags: audiokit

by AKFrequencyTracker ,I can catch the frequence.but if the guitar is playing three strings, I can get these three frequencies at the same time.I mean can we have multiple frequencies of output?

Answer (score 2):

In a word, no. We do not have polyphonic pitch tracking at this time, sorry.

Comment: Just checking in to see if there have been any updates here; I'm looking to do polyphonic analysis as well.  @Aurelius Prochazka

Comment: No, a few people have promised to add it but nothing yet. #opensource